# Make minimum price in shopping cart Magento

Tags: magento

Everywhere I see, can't find any info about it.

I need that people who adding to cart product ±20eur, can't process checkout, because shopping cart need to be ±50 eur. How to do this?

Comment: While you didn't do your research online I can't find the answer easily on stackoverflow, therefor I don't think the -1 is justified. +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Configuration > Sales > Minimum Order Amount
```

Setting that should do the trick.

Comment: What if you wanted to exclude a certain product, think theres any solution for that?